# Imagick loads images on local server, but not godaddy server. PHP

Tags: php, image, imagick

I have an image that is uploaded to the server, I then get the image information and resize using imagick, this works great on my local server (xammp) but when I upload to site to godaddy, only certain images load. Here is a snippet of code;

```
$image = frameEngine($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
$tempHeight = $image->getHeight();
$tempWidth  = $image->getWidth();
$inches     = $image->getInches();
```

In the class frameEngine it reads;

```
Class frameEngine {

private $image;
private $height;
private $width;
private $dpi;

function __construct($file) {
   $this->image = new Imagick(realpath($file));
   $this->width = $this->image->getImageWidth();
   $this->height = $this->image->getImageHeight();
   $this->dpi = $this->image->getImageResolution();

}

public function getHeight() {
   return $this->height;
}

public function getWidth() {
   return $this->width;
}

public function getInches() {
   $dpi = $this->dpi;
   $iw = round(($this->width / $dpi['x']*100)/100,2);
   $ih = round(($this->height / $dpi['y']*100)/100,2);
   return array('w' => $iw, 'h' => $ih);    
}

}
```

I get a division by zero error in getInches() obviously because Imagick is returning 0 as image height and width, therefore I believe imagick is failing on the image. The image is obviously fine as it works on my local server.

Comment: Which is your hosting plan?

Comment: Shared hosting sucks, as you are held captive to their software stacks. You may want to consider moving a cheap vps (linode, aws, etc).

Comment: Linux Hosting w/Cpanel, the Imagick module is the same as the one on my local server, I narrowed it down to $this->image->getImageResolution() returning the 0,0 for DPI

Comment: Any difference between the 'certain images' and the fail images? The size? format ?

Comment: Yeah there are slight image size differences, a slightly smaller pixel image worked fine, same format 'jpg'

Answer (score 0):

Two things before you come to the conclusion that Imagick is not working

1. Make a test script and use `phpinfo()` . Hit the page from your browser and look for imagick mentioned in that page. If this is not mentioned then boom! you need to contact your hosting provider for this
2. Secondly, make sure that file upload is enabled and file is uploaded properly by using old-school `var_dump`

Hope this helps fella!

Comment: phpinfo() shows imagick, both look identical on local and godaddy server. when I var_dump the file is there, like I said in my last reply height and width are returning proper results, but getImageResolution is returning 0's.